# Handsontable - How to prepopulate a cell's editor with a formula

Tags: javascript, spreadsheet, handsontable

How does one prepopulate a cell in a row with a formula like `=A1+B1`?

I have tried using a custom renderer but when I double click on that cell with the pre-populated formula, when the cell shows its "editor" the formula `=A1+B1` cannot be seen.

What's worse is that if I enter a valid numeric value in both the `A1` cell and the `B1` cell that it DOES correctly calculate and follow the formula,

However, ONCE I enter a invalid value either in `A1` or `B1`, the cell holding the `=A1+B1` formula suddenly turns into **#value** and just holds on to that value FOREVER, even if I re-edit `A1` and `B1` cells to hold a proper numeric value.

As mentioned above, I have been able to prepopulate a cell following the example on this link:
http://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.1/demo-pre-populating-new-rows.html

The example on that link however only prepopulates a cell with texts and not formulas that are expected run.

Here is the renderer I used.

```
function defaultValueRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    var args = arguments;

    var plusOne = row + 1;
    var formula = '=C' + plusOne + '+D' + plusOne;
    args[5] = formula;
    td.style.color = '#999';

    Handsontable.cellTypes['formula'].renderer.apply(this, args);
}
```

Comment: That's because the renderer is used to describe how the data will get DISPLAYED. It doesn't (shouldn't) modify data, so this is not the place to do it. Not sure how to pre-populate cells or if that's available yet. You're looking at version 0.16 which is a bit old now. You may want to give version 0.20 a shot and see if the bug you see at least is gone. Otherwise, file on the github issues page

Comment: Yes...I believe you are right...the question is how does one use the editor to enter and change the value since using the renderer to display the value like the example provided does not work without negative side effects...0.20 .1 is essentially the same... http://docs.handsontable.com/0.20.1/demo-pre-populating-new-rows.html

Comment: Well, if it's the placeholders that you want, I'd use the `afterCreateRow` event. In here, check the index of the new row and manually modify the data source. Done.

Comment: Hi...this sounds like solid alternative.... and by 'modify the data source' do you mean use setDataAtCell ?  e.g.   http://docs.handsontable.com/0.20.1/Core.html#setDataAtCell

Comment: Well, that's one option, yeah. I meant that you're passing in the reference to a data object (I hope) so you should have access to that data object at all times. But yeah, the internal method is probably better since you want to fire all appropriate events.